# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value on laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a
> default value

why i got that error? and how to fix it?

here's my controlller looks like

```
    public function create(Request $request, Question $question)
    {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'standart_id' => 'required',
            'question.*.question' => 'required',
            'question.*.question_id' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'question.*.answer' => 'required',
            'files_link' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        $data['user_id'] = Auth()->id();

//        dd($data);
//        dd($request->input('question.*.standart_id'));

        $responses = $question->responses()->createMany($data['question']);

    }
```

here is what i got on diedump `$data`

```
array:5 [▼
  "standart_id" => "2"
  "user_id" => 3
  "files_link" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auditee/1/respons/"
  "description" => "asdasd"
  "question" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "question" => "test"
      "question_id" => "4"
      "answer" => "Ya"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▶]
    2 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
]
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

**EDITED**

route for create

```
Route::post('/standart/{question}/answer/post', [App\Http\Controllers\ResponsController::class, 'create']);
```

response model

```
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }

    public function standart()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Standart::class);
    }
```

question model

```
    public function standard()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Standart::class);
    }

    public function responses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Response::class);
    }
```

standart model

```
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    public function responses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Response::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error says you are not passing `user_id` .

```
$result=collect($request->question)->map(function ($item)use($request) {
  $item['user_id'] = $request->user_id;
  $item['standart_id'] = $request->standart_id;
  $item['files_link'] = $request->files_link;
  $item['description'] = $request->description;
  return $item;
});


Response::insert($result->toArray());
```

Comment: it changed into this `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'standart_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: now its `files_link`, and when i added `files_link` it turn to error field `description`

Comment: @UyyU add both file link and description same way how i added user_id and standart_id

Comment: yes already added, and now i got error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'question_id' cannot be null (SQL:`

Comment: it means question array has null value for question_id  .so check dd($request->question) and see if  any null

Comment: i found the array, and the the data inside it

Comment: but for question_id  its empty one of the array.check properly every array

Comment: yes its empty on dd($request->question_id);

Comment: no .you have to dd($request->question) inside of that multiple array is there.so check each array question_id

Comment: @UyyU.can you post  Question  and related model in your question

Comment: try adding    protected $guarded = ['id']; in all model

Comment: the array from `dd($request->question)` looks same as the one that i posted, but it only shows `"question" => array:3 [▼` to the bottom

Comment: @UyyU .after adding id in guarded still error

Comment: still the same error, `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'question_id' cannot be null`

Comment: error is clear so yuo have to check all array inside dd($request->question) .you have to open all array node

Comment: here's how the array looks like  http://prntscr.com/174unmw

Comment: can you dd($result->toArray()) and show screenshot

Comment: looks good . can you show model code screenshot of Response i need  full code screenshot

Comment: @UyyU.i really not sure what exactly are you trying to do but  you can do Response::insert($result->toArray())